# Linking to an external stylesheet to see updates on the fly

Tags: html, css

We are looking at an external website example.com.

I would like to create an ad hoc dev environment where I can update a stylesheet on my computer and see the changes on the actual live site.

I could just use the inspect element feature but what if I accidentally refresh.

I added a stylesheet to my public dropbox folder. The folder is linked to my desktop so every time I save the .css file on my computer, it syncs to my public dropbox folder - the edits to the stylesheet are live.

I then edited the html using the inspect element feature in chrome. I edited the html in the `<head>` section and added the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18083818/stylegavin.css">
```

I had expected the site on my screen to update - no updates appeared.

1. Is my approach to seeing on the fly css edits the best way?
2. Why are my changes not being seen on the live site when I link to the stylesheet in the head?

Here's a picture of the stylesheet added via inspect element:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way for checking if your stylesheet is working the way you want it to work but what software are you using to develop the website? Dreamweaver? If so Dreamweaver has a feature which would allow you to do this which would be a lot easier and safer just incase, say for whatever reason your dropbox account was compromised or if the stylesheet was accidentally deleted then at least you can monitor your changes through an FTP Account.

For your second question: you may need to refresh your page to see the effects as it may take some time for the dropbox to sync this new file to its' server.

Can I also just point out that your CSS: `a#header-links-blue-button.button.hblue-button` may struggle to work as you've correctly stated that you are defining an id selector withing the `<a>` tag, but you have also used `.` in the name which may confuse the browser when looking for classes and id's. It is usually good practice not to use `.` and `#` in the names of class and id selectors.

Comment: I'm not developing the account per-se. I'm checking to see what small changes in CSS would do to someone else's website. For example, if you wanted to make changes to bbc.co.uk you could open inspect element and make some edits to see what they look like. But if you were going to make a little more substantial changes to bbc.co.uk (a site owned by someone else) how could you change the stylesheet used on your own computer to see what the changes look like? Rather than using inspect element?

Comment: Hmm i see now what you mean! I'm not sure there is any other way to do this except via the inspect element feature.